# Volley POST StringRequest not giving any response

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I've given permissions for Internet access to my application and the URL I'm using is right (I can do POST requests through postman correctly). But in my application the requests fail:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = Email.getText().toString();
            final String password = Password.getText().toString();


            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("exitoso")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Todo mal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hubo un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Params.put("email", email);
                    Params.put("password", password);
                    return Params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=\"UTF-8");
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
```

My emulator does not give me any responses, just stays on login activity (which is the main one).

Comment: What is your "server_url" here ?

Comment: String server_url = "https://localhost/ingresar.php";

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild the app, honestly it was that now it works.

Comment: I realize this is a self-answer, but please don't call people names. We have a [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) here. Be nice, even to yourself :-).